# UITableViewCell' has no member 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The error is from `let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("todoCell") as! UITableViewCell`
    how can I deal with this question and why it has problem?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource {
        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableViewCell!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            }
        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
            return 20
        }
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("todoCell") as! UITableViewCell
            return cell
        }
        }
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that `self.tableview` returns a `UITableViewCell` object and that `UITableViewCell` doesn't have a `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` member.

Answer (score 6):

Your `tableView` outlet is mistakenly declared as a `UITableViewCell` instead of a `UITableView`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

BTW - inside the various data source and delegate methods, use the `tableView` parameter instead of accessing the property.

Example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("todoCell") as! UITableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having that problem until i figured out that this syntax changed for swift3

swift3:

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier , for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

before:

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell